# store.getstate is not a function in next js how to get rid of this in nextjs 13?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

i am getting below error
Next.js is up to date

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: store.getState is not a function

```
"use client";

import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import productSlice from "./features/productSlice";

const persistedStateJson = localStorage.getItem("myState");

let persistedState = {};

if (persistedStateJson) {
  persistedState = JSON.parse(persistedStateJson);
}

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    productSlice
  },
  preloadedState: persistedState,
});

//set local storage on store change
store.subscribe(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("myState", JSON.stringify(store));
});

export default store;
```

configured the redux store

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately omitted the stack trace, so there's no telling where that is coming from right now, but there are two general problems here I want to point out, both stemming from the same nuance:

**This component is a client component, but it will still SSR because that's what Next.js does with the App Router!**

- That means that this exported `store` constant will be shared between all your users and all pages that are SSRed. You need to create this `store` instance inside of a component and keep it as a `ref` or as local component state, just before passing it into your `Provider`. You cannot have it as a module-level constant.
- That also means that your code here would error out because `localStorage` does not exist on the server. You will need to wrap this code into a `typeof window !== "undefined"` check.

```js
//set local storage on store change
if (typeof window !== "undefiend") {
  store.subscribe(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("myState", JSON.stringify(store));
  });
}
```

It also means that the SSRed part here will always start with an empty store (since the server cannot access localStorage of the users browser). This will probably cause a lot of problems down the line here, as the server will render completely different markup from the client.